# How to redirect only www with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, web, subdomain

Can you please help me how to redirect ONLY `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`?

I have some subdomains (`http://sub1.example.com`; `http://sub2.example.com`...) and I don't want them to be redirected also.

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With that, what I'm getting is that when I access to `http://example.com` it redirects correctly to `http://www.example.com` but when I access to `http://sub1.example.com` it redirects to `http://www.www.sub1.example.com/sub1_folder/sub1_folder/`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$` to only target that one specific host name without any subdomain.

Comment: @CBroe It worked, thanks. Let me ask you - is it possible to have something more generic? Instead of having `^example\.com$`, is it possible to have something that not point to this specific url?

Comment: The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) does only mention the use of server variables for the TestString, not for the CondPattern. If they would work in the pattern as well (don’t know), _and_ if your SERVER_NAME was set to only the base domain (example.com in this example), then that might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a more generic regex pattern if you know your domain will be XXX.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or even better:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```